# Linux shutdown with countdown. (made with while)

Tags: linux, bash, shutdown

Hello I want to create a script that shutdowns Linux after a certain time (e.g 15 seconds) with a countdown displayed in the terminal (Linux is shutting down after 15s.). It has to be with while.

Comment: Could you please show us your attempt to the problem?

Comment: There is already [shutdown](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) which can (optionally) take a time parameter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not relevant to other readers. Mainly because of the (absurd homework?) requirement "it has to be with while".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=15
while [ 1 ] 
do
    if [ ${COUNTER} -eq 0 ]
    then
        break
    fi
    echo "Linux is shutting down after ${COUNTER}s."
    sleep 1
    COUNTER=$( echo "${COUNTER}-1" | bc )
done
sudo poweroff
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to display the counter on the screen, this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

seconds=15
echo "Linux is shutting down after ${seconds}s"          
date_1=$((`date +%s` + $seconds))

while [ "$date_1" -ge `date +%s` ]; do
echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date_1 - `date +%s` )) +%H:%M:%S)\r"
     done

echo -e "Do you really want to shutdown the system? Press [Y/y] to shutdown or [n/N] to cancel/exit:" 
read var
if [[ "$var" == "y" ]] || [[ "$var" == "Y" ]]
then
sudo poweroff
elif [[ "$var" == "n" ]] || [[ "$var" == "N" ]]
then
exit 1
fi
```

Basically, it'll accept [Y/y] from the user to shutdown and [n/N] to exit.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to add "Press "y" to shutdown and "n" to cancel."
I've tried something like:
"...
echo "Do you want to shutdown the system y/n. y to accept n to cancel."
read a
if [$a != y ]
then
       echo  -e "The computer won't shutdown."
fi
while [ $a==y ] 
do
if [ ${counter} -eq 0 ]
then 
           break
fi 
echo "The computer will now shutdown"

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check and let me know if it's fine.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much :).